# Why are my sims complaining about too many injuries?

Tags: simcity-2013

I only have 1500 population now. I'm trying to reach high density first and give them everything they need, but they are telling me that "There are too many injuries". I have a clinic which is never full with 3 ambulance cars on the opposite side of the road so I don't get it. How can this be solved?

Answer (score 4):

Education is the key here actually. It will lower the chances of your sim's getting sick or injured as well as decrease the amount of power/water that they will consume. It does not matter the level of education but you should be aware that anything above a high school will affect your industrial production.

Comment: Affect your industrial production negatively?

Comment: I have a basic school already with 550desk...and we only have 300students...so i dont really know..:S

Comment: @SocioMatt: Only 'dumb' sims want to work in mines. The general strategy is to level up your cities (industry/colleges + people/education) at the same time.

Comment: @SocioMatt: Mousing over the university will tell you that it increases tech levels around the university, so it's a beneficial thing

Comment: @Neoshane This means Sims are not making it to school, add more buses.